# Edit Windows 10 boot config (BCEDIT?) to disable Safe Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, batch-file, safe-mode

I recently had a weird issue where while using my Windows 10 laptop that had been working fine, suddenly I couldn't create folders anymore, neither in GUI nor CLI (command line). My laptop display stopped working about 3 years ago and since then I use an external monitor. I booted in Safe Mode/Safe Boot via MSCONFIG. But, on reboot I just had a black screen.

So, I need to find a way to get out of Safe Mode. So far, I've tried:

- **Boot Options keys:** Tried standard boot options keys (F8, F12, ESC) on startup to see if that would help -- no-go
- **P Functions:** Hitting some "P" combination recommended in forums -- no-go
- **Blind navigation:** -- no-go. The theory is this: *If I can't see what I am doing, but I know the exact key stroke sequence, then I should be able to accomplish what I need*. Seems like it should work, but maybe there are extra screens like login, warning popups, confirmations etc that those who have recommended blind navigation haven't accounted for.
- **Closing Laptop:** I have wireless keyboard and mouse connect to my laptop so I tried quickly shutting monitor immediately after hard power on -- no-go

### KNOWN THINGS:

- The hard drive works fine and I can even access the data and files by connecting it with a USB external adapter to another laptop
- I can't do any process that involves booting into Windows and using a mouse
- I don't have a similar / same-model laptop on which to insert the hard drive

### SPECS:

- Windows 10 64-bit

### MY QUESTION:

- At this point, the only thing I can think of is can I edit the boot config or startup files? Before Microsoft gave us the registry, there were files like **autoexec.bat**, **config.sys**, and **boot.ini**. I'm wondering if there is some simple text file I can edit to disable the safe boot so I can boot normal again?
- Would **BCEDIT** be the correct file to edit to disable safe boot?

Comment: If your thought is to use another device to modify the BCD on this HDD that won't work. It does not sound like you have a way to modify the BCD on the system itself.  The fact you cannot log into Safe Mode indicates, even if you disable Safe Mode, you still won't be able to boot into Windows.

Comment: It seems like you have two options: 1. Replace the faulty internal screen in order to find out what the problem is and decide whether it is worthwhile repairing, 2. Replace the computer.

Comment: Another option: Image the disk and boot it in a VM

Comment: @DukeNukem Can you elaborate? I have VirtualBox installed on a newer laptop. How can I image an existing hard drive? I used to use Acronis, but not since it went un-free. I know about Ghost, but I think that has dissapeared from the market.

Comment: You can image it directly with VirtualBox. First, connect it with your USB adapter and go to Start > Right-click Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management. You will see your disks listed on the bottom. Note the disk # of the disk you want to image. Second, open the command prompt and cd into your VirtualBox directory. Third, run this comand: "VBoxManage convertfromraw \\.\PhysicalDriveX <path> --format VDI", where X is the digit you noted above and <path> is where you want to save the image (e.g. C:\SomePath\Image.vdi). Last, create a new VM and pick the saved image as its disk.

Comment: @DukeNukem Thanks for this! I will give it a try.